# Jquery Mobile - Phonegap : "pagecontainerchange" not woring in windows phone 8 app

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, windows-phone

I have created an application using phonegap/cordova for android, which is working perfectly. now I am using same code to create windows phone 8 app and everything is working except following:

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerchange", function( event, ui ) {
     var activePage = ui.toPage[0].id;
     var fromPage = ui.options.fromPage[0].id;
     if (activePage == 'communication') {
        getCommunicationDetails();
    } else if (activePage == 'contacts') {
        getContactDetails();
    }
)};
```

Event is not firing. Is there anything similar to this I can use which can run on Android, Windows Phone and IOS?

Comment: Which JQM version are you using? Do you want to run function before page is shown, or when it's shown?

Comment: Thanks for reply Omar.I am using jquery-1.11.1.min.js and jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js If you will see above example code I want to call it after page changes according to active page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling this event inside $(document).ready(function(){}); is solved my issue.

Thanks
Jaya